# Export SQL Server 2008 R2 Database

Tags: sql-server-2008, copy, export

I have a database in SQL Server 2008 R2. This database contains some tables, stored procs, data, etc.

I need a way to get this database to someone else. When I just performed a backup of it, I wasn't able to restore it on my own machine to a random "TestDB" I created. How would I export the database I have so someone could take it and set it up in their SQL Server instance to use.

Thanks!

Comment: "When I just performed a backup of it, I wasn't able to restore it on my own machine to a random "TestDB" I created" - why not?

Comment: It said the backup contained a DB that was not contained in the DB I was trying to restore.

Comment: then you need to click the checkbox that says "Force overwrite" !

Comment: It was probably looking for the original database name and not 'TestDB'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.  1.make sure the restore sql server is the same, or higher version (eg sql 2008 vs 2008 R2).  2. It may sound dumb but sql 2008 doesn't pick what to restore from the backup.  You have to explicitly pick the content to restore.